# Is there an easy example that shows that the initial ideal of a radical ideal is not necessarily a radical ideal itself?

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Is there an easy example that shows that the initial ideal of a radical ideal is not necessarily a radical ideal itself?

This is the converse of if the initial ideal of an ideal is radical, then the ideal is radical.

Also, how can I create more examples?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169096/showing-that-if-the-initial-ideal-of-i-is-radical-then-i-is-radical

Comment: @user26857 Yes, that is the result for which I am looking for an example that shows its converse is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=K[X,Y,Z]$ and $I=(X^2-YZ)$. If one considers the lexicographical order on $R$ with $X>Y>Z$ then $\operatorname{in}(I)=(X^2)$.

Comment: There is an interesting result of Migliore and Nagel which says that *any monomial ideal is the initial ideal of a radical ideal*.

Comment: You can create more examples by using irreducible polynomials as I did.

Comment: I found an example using the CAS Singular. Your example is much simpler, however. And I will look for that result. Thanks.