# If the initial monomial ideal $in_<(I)$ is square free, then $I$ is a radical ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals

I have to prove the following statement: Let $I$ be an ideal and < be any monomial order. If the initial monomial ideal $in_<(I)$ is square free, then $I$ is a radical ideal.

If I can prove that $in_<(I)$ is radical then the proof would be done because of this: [Showing that if the initial ideal of I is radical, then I is radical.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169096/showing-that-if-the-initial-ideal-of-i-is-radical-then-i-is-radical)

I am a bit stuck on proving that though, any help or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Show that the radical ideal of a monomial ideal is itself monomial.